# String copy inconsistency

Tags: c, gcc

I'm trying to solve a problem on Hacker Rank (Sorting Array of Strings) https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/sorting-array-of-strings/problem?isFullScreen=true
issue is the output is not as expected (same code works on GCC and outputs correct results but incorrect output on hacker rank)

in `void string_sort` if I change it to:

```
char *temp = arr[i4];
arr[i4] = arr[i4 + 1];
arr[i4 + 1] = temp;
```

instead of `strcpy` it works fine so I assume there's something that I don't about `strcpy` or I'm using it incorrectly.

*****NOTE: The implementation of the `main` function is a preset by hacker rank which I cannot change. I only implemented the 5 functions before the `main` which are `lexicographic_sort` `lexicographic_sort_reverse` `sort_by_number_of_distinct_characters` `sort_by_length` `string_sort`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
int lexicographic_sort(const char* a, const char* b) {
    if(strcmp(a, b) < 0){
        return 2;
    }
    else{
        return 4;
    }
}

int lexicographic_sort_reverse(const char* a, const char* b) {
    if(strcmp(a, b) < 0){
        return 4;
    }
    else{
        return 2;
    }
}

int sort_by_number_of_distinct_characters(const char* a, const char* b) {
    int Arr[26]= {0}, counterA= 0, counterB= 0;
    
    for(int i1= 0; i1<strlen(a); i1++)
    {
        Arr[a[i1] - 'a']++;
        if(Arr[a[i1] - 'a'] == 1){
            counterA++;
        }
    }
    
    for(int i1= 0; i1<26; i1++){
        Arr[i1]= 0;
    }
    for(int i1= 0; i1<strlen(b); i1++){
        Arr[b[i1] - 'a']++;
        if(Arr[b[i1] - 'a'] == 1){
            counterB++;
        }
    }
    
    if(counterA < counterB){
        return 2;
    }
    else if(counterA == counterB){
        return lexicographic_sort(a, b);
    }
    else{
        return 4;
    }
}

int sort_by_length(const char* a, const char* b) {
    if(strlen(a) < strlen(b)){
        return 2;
    }
    else if(strlen(a) == strlen(b)){
        return lexicographic_sort(a, b);
    }
    else{
        return 4;
    }
}

void string_sort(char** arr,const int len,int (*cmp_func)(const char* a, const char* b)){
    for(int i3= 0; i3 < (len-1); i3++){
        for(int i4= 0; i4 < (len-1)-i3; i4++){
            if(cmp_func(arr[i4], arr[i4+1]) == 4){
                char temp[1024]= {0};
                strcpy(temp, arr[i4]);
                strcpy(arr[i4], arr[i4+1]);
                strcpy(arr[i4+1], temp);
            }
        }
    }
}


int main() 
{
    int n;
    scanf("%d", &n);
  
    char** arr;
    arr = (char**)malloc(n * sizeof(char*));
  
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        *(arr + i) = malloc(1024 * sizeof(char));
        scanf("%s", *(arr + i));
        *(arr + i) = realloc(*(arr + i), strlen(*(arr + i)) + 1);
    }
  
    string_sort(arr, n, lexicographic_sort);
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf("%s\n", arr[i]);
    printf("\n");

    string_sort(arr, n, lexicographic_sort_reverse);
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf("%s\n", arr[i]); 
    printf("\n");

    string_sort(arr, n, sort_by_length);
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf("%s\n", arr[i]);    
    printf("\n");

    string_sort(arr, n, sort_by_number_of_distinct_characters);
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf("%s\n", arr[i]); 
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: Think about the size of the buffers you are copying with `strcpy`. Hint: `*(arr + i) = realloc(*(arr + i), strlen(*(arr + i)) + 1);`

Comment: Why do you think, That copying a string is the same as copying char?

Comment: @Thallius They're not copying a char. They're swapping pointers.

Comment: Get out of the habit of writing `*(arr + i)`. This is equivalent to the clearer `arr[i]`.

Comment: Aside: you call `strlen` more times than necessary, notably in `sort_by_length()`.

Comment: @WeatherVane Any decent optimizer will perform common subexpression elimination.

Comment: @Barmar across functions?

Comment: @WeatherVane No. But http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization

Comment: @Barmar yeah, lovely mantra, but it's not evil to do that here at the outset. The other side of the coin is to write sloppy code and say "heck, the compiler will sort that out for me!"

Comment: @WeatherVane I'm not even sure how you expect them to combine `strlen()` across functions.

Comment: Suspect `char temp[1024]` is not safe. The assignment indicates that the "Total Length of all the strings <= 2500" and doesn't say anything about the length of an individual string so you should probably use at least 2501.

Comment: "_implementation of the main function is a preset by hacker rank_" That is very bad code. A good reason to not use it (or expect to learn from it.) Challenge: Revise `main()` to be robust...

Comment: @jarmod "supplied code" loading from stdin would blow up if string length exceeds 1023 (with room for `'\0'` )...

Comment: What is with the inexplicable use of `2` and `4` versus something conventional like `0` and `1`, or even `-1` and `1`?

Comment: @RaymondChen Can you please explain further?

Comment: @jarmod in the main function written by hacker rank before scanning the strings they set the size to 1024 which indicates that the tests will not have a string larger than 1024 and just for the sake of testing I did try 2501 and same issue

Comment: @tadman No real reason xD

Comment: Embrace the [*Principle of Least Surprise*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment) and try and pick things that make sense versus those that just lead to questions.

Comment: `strcpy(arr[i4], arr[i4+1]);` means "Take the string that starts at the address recorded in `arr[i4+1] ` and copy it to the memory starting at the address recorded in `arr[i4]`. But you don't know that there is enough memory starting at the address recorded in `arr[i4]` to hold all the characters of the string that starts at the address recorded in `arr[i4+1]`. In particular, if the string at `arr[i4]` is shorter than the string at `arr[i4+1]`, then you don't have enough memory. Run your program with a memory checker enabled to see the buffer overflow.

Comment: @MohamedAhmed no, they don't set the maximum length to 1024. They pre-allocate 1024 bytes for each string but they attempt to read whatever the user enters, however long it is. That may crash, it may not, but the original point still stands. That said, this is *not* the main problem with your code. It is *a* problem, not *the* problem.